# Eloquent: Dynamic model for use with multiple tables

Tags: php, eloquent

I need to have 1 model where I can switch out the connection and table name. This seems to be almost working, however if I remove the `orderBy` then the `where` clause isn't added to the query.

`$table` is a collection which contains my table name.

This is the model:

**DynamicModel.php**

```
<?php

    namespace App\Models;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class DynamicModel extends Model
    {
        public function scopeSet($query, $table, $connection)
        {
            $this->setTable($table);
            $this->setConnection($connection);
            return $this;
        }
    }
```

This is how i'm changing the table name:

```
$result = DB::select(DB::raw("SHOW KEYS FROM {$table->getAttribute('table')} WHERE Key_name = 'PRIMARY'"));
$primaryKey = $result[0]->Column_name;

/** @var Model $demo */
$demo = DynamicModel::set($table->getAttribute('table'), 'demo')->orderBy($primaryKey);
$demo->where([ 'dealer_id' => $website->dealer_id ]);
$demoData = $demo->toSql();
```

So, this is the resulting SQL with the `orderBy` clause.

> select * from `tablename` where (`dealer_id` = ?) order by `da_id` asc

But if I remove the `orderBy` clause then I get this:

> select * from `tablename`

Any ideas?

Comment: what is `$table` variable?

Comment: See updated post.

Comment: Any errors in log?

Comment: Try to chain `where()` before `orderBy()`

Comment: This misses the point of using a model in the first place. Why not just use the Query Builder at this point?